# How to import javascript function from file without running entire js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have page1.html which uses blah.js. One of the things blah.js does is run a function1() when the page is loaded. I would like to use function2() from blah.js in page2.html without blah.js running function1(). I thought I could add

```
export {function2}
```

to blah.js and then just import function2() by adding

```
<script type = "module">
import { function2 } from './blah.js'
</script>
```

to page2.html. But this seems to have the same functionality as if I just imported the file as normal:

```
  <script defer src="blah.js"></script>
```

i.e. function1() runs in page2 in both cases. How can I get access to function2() without running the other parts of blah.js?

Comment: Split `function2` into another file and have both pages import it

Comment: Alternatively, modify `blah.js` so it doesn't run `function1` when loaded. Instead have page1 call `function1` manually

Answer (score 1):

If you import from a module, *all* of that module's *top-level* code will run. That is, given

```
console.log('running');
export const foo = 5;
```

There is no way to import `foo` without also logging the text.

One good approach to this problem (and a very good practice in general) is to **avoid side-effects** at the top level of modules. If you have something that's a side-effect, put it into a function instead, and export that function, so that it only runs on demand, instead of every time anything from the file is imported.

So, you probably want to change your file to something like:

```
export const runFunction1WhenPageLoads = () => {
  const fnToRun = () => {
    // insert code here
  };
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    fnToRun();
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fnToRun);
  }
};
export const function2 = () => {
  // insert code here
};
```

Comment: "If you import from a module, all of that module's top-level code will run." Thank you for the info, I didn't know this was the case. Given that, yeah I can find plenty of workarounds.